# Google Spreadsheet: Editing Status options in `Assignment tracker` template

Tags: google-sheets

I am using **Assignment tracker** default template of Google spreadsheet. The `Status` column has four default options *Done*, *In progress*, ... and `Subject` column has four options *Maths*, *Biology*, ....

The options for `Subject` could be edited from `Subjects` tab, but from where can the options of `Status` be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click cell `D5`.

Choose *Data* from the menu and then *Data validation* from the dropdown menu:
[image: Data validation menu item]

When the Data Validation dialog appears, the *Cell range:* box will say `Assignments!D5`; add to that so that it says `Assignments!D5:D`.

*Criteria* will show *List of items* with a four-item list that is currently being used as the options for those drop-downs in the cells. Change that list to suit your needs.
[image: Data validation dialog box]

---

You may also then want to change the conditional formatting to suit your needs. To do that:

Again, select cell `D5` (though it could be any).

Choose *Format* from the menu, and then *Conditional Formatting* from the drop-down menu.

When the Conditional Formatting dialog appears, the top two items will be `Text is exactly 'Not started' D5:D41` and `Text is exactly 'In progress ' D5:D41`.

Since you will have changed the Data Validation list to contain other items, you can either

a. hover over each of these entries in the *Conditional Formatting* dialog until the trashcan appears and click that to delete the conditional formatting rule, **or**

b. click on the rule and edit the text and formatting to match your new list items and preferences. You may need to add more rules. Just use the same range (`D5:D41`) and *Text is exactly,* like the other two, filling in your own new item and preferred formatting.

Comment: Great answer! Hope you don't mind I added a couple of screenshots and some formatting to make it even clearer.

Comment: Perfect, Vidar. I'm sure that will help many visual learners along the way. Thanks.